# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I don't find out why this error. I become more patient after googling more time with this error. It may be a database connection related issue. But I can't identify it. But the last line indicates that No suitable driver.  Please, anyone, help me.

*In this project I have only used required jar file.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:572)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:360)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getCustomers(Unknown Source)
    com.luv2code.springdemo.controller.CustomerController.listCustomers(CustomerController.java:25)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:107)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:259)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:267)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:471)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:537)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:572)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:360)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getCustomers(Unknown Source)
    com.luv2code.springdemo.controller.CustomerController.listCustomers(CustomerController.java:25)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:692)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:259)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:267)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:471)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:537)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:572)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:360)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getCustomers(Unknown Source)
    com.luv2code.springdemo.controller.CustomerController.listCustomers(CustomerController.java:25)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1469)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:259)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:267)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:471)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:537)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:572)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:360)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getCustomers(Unknown Source)
    com.luv2code.springdemo.controller.CustomerController.listCustomers(CustomerController.java:25)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:298)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

Entity

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Customer() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

Controller

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
@SessionAttributes
public class CustomerController {

    // need to inject the customer dao
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the dao
        List<Customer> theCustomers = customerDAO.getCustomers();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("customers", theCustomers);

        return "list-customers";
    }
}
```

CustomerDAO

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;

public interface CustomerDAO {

    public List<Customer> getCustomers();

}
```

CustomerDAOImpl

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.dao;

import java.util.List; 

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    // need to inject the session factory
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

        // get the current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // create a query
        Query<Customer> theQuery = 
                currentSession.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);

        // execute query and get result list
        List<Customer> customers = theQuery.getResultList();

        // return the results       
        return customers;
    }
}
```

spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="springstudent" />
        <property name="password" value="springstudent" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted error usually comes when `c3p0` cannot identify the provided driver. Make sure you have the `MySQL` driver available in the classpath. You should have this `mysql` dependency on the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.19</version> <!--suitable version-->
    </dependency>
```

Do a `mvn clean install` and check. If you got this line from copy and paste from internet, try typing it yourself and see. Because copy paste could have embedded hidden characters.

```
<property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
```

If you are not using maven then you need to add this jar to your classpath manually. Download the jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.19 and add that to classpath.

Comment: I am not using any mvn tool

Comment: Then you need to add the jar file manually to your projects classpath. See the edited answer. Depending on your ide the approach will be different